# Changing socket options dynamically

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, posix

I'm hoping that I can change optvals of `setsockopt` back and forth, quickly, and many times, over the lifetime of a single socket.

Specifically, I need to enable and disable `TCP_NODELAY` depending on some business logic. Some packets need to go out with `TCP_NODELAY` and some packets are bulk, and should go out without it. We know in advance, and so I'd like to set the appropriate option. It's a long story -- this question is **not** about the merits or demerits of enabling or disabling Nagle!

Is there a delay before the `setsockopt` call takes effect?

Comment: Shouldn't be, but it doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: And of course if there is pending send data when you change it, it will apply to that data as well. Not a. Useful technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referencing source, it should work without delay, immediately sets option on tcp_sk:

do_tcp_setsockopt

```
...
case TCP_NODELAY:
    if (val) {
        /* TCP_NODELAY is weaker than TCP_CORK, so that
         * this option on corked socket is remembered, but
         * it is not activated until cork is cleared.
         *
         * However, when TCP_NODELAY is set we make
         * an explicit push, which overrides even TCP_CORK
         * for currently queued segments.
         */
        tp->nonagle |= TCP_NAGLE_OFF|TCP_NAGLE_PUSH;
        tcp_push_pending_frames(sk);
    } else {
        tp->nonagle &= ~TCP_NAGLE_OFF;
    }
    break;
```

[__tcp_push_pending_frames](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1b1050cdc5cdde43177b375b5f22dc070d45d8f8/net/ipv4/tcp_output.c#L2288)

[tcp_write_xmit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1b1050cdc5cdde43177b375b5f22dc070d45d8f8/net/ipv4/tcp_output.c#L2020)